# Best online mathematics videos?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, examples, online-resources

I know of two good mathematics videos available online, namely:

1. Sphere inside out ([part I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVVfs4zKrgk) and  [part II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7d13SgqUXg))
2. [Moebius transformation revealed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z1fIsUNhO4)

Do you know of any other good math videos? Share.

Comment: The sphere eversion video is available in one part on Google Videos: http://bit.ly/2Bmj3Z

Comment: The sphere eversion video is great, and it seems like a really good way to explain topology and the idea of an invariant to a non-mathematician.  On the other hand, I wouldn't expect someone to sit for 20 minutes just to find out what I care about.  Does anyone have recommendations of shorter videos that achieve similar goals?

Comment: I protected this one as it seems a clear candidate for this and as it just got reactivated and thus I noticed it. If you see a problem with this please let me know, or bring it up on meta.

Comment: You missed to specify for which group / level of knowledge you are searching the "best mathematics videos". This makes it hard to answer. If you have 10 to 18 years old, you find great video material here (in German, all Youtube videos are with subtitles, thus translatable to English): http://www.matheretter.de/mathe-videos

Comment: @HarrisonBrown: The link you give appears to be broken in the meantime.
Probably you mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_w4HYXuo9M.

Comment: If I had more videos like this I would post as an answer.  Here are some review solutions for my students in the United States for Finite Mathematics.  I was able to find a way to write on the slides.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDoqbx4zO2E&t=7s

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I have compiled a list (1500+) of math videos at http://pinterest.com/mathematicsprof/ .   If anyone is aware of others, please send them to me.

Comment: Did you go through the all the videos in this question?

Answer (score 80):

77 instructional videos on category theory:

https://www.youtube.com/TheCatsters

I know you said "only one video per post", but I'm not posting 77 times...

Comment: Gosh!  Are they up to 77 now?

Answer (score 44):

Most of the talks at MSRI are videotaped and placed on the web here:

http://www.msri.org/communications/vmath/index_html

Answer (score 39):

My personal all-time favorite is the Klein Four with their song "Finite Simple Group (of Order Two)"... it has lots of puns on topology in it, but I guess it doesn't teach anything.

[Here's the link to the "Finite Simple Group" song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BipvGD-LCjU)

Comment: The song may not teach anything, but I think it's contributed positively to my education! Listening to it every once in a while gives me evidence that I'm actually learning stuff, because the song keeps getting funnier. ^_^

Answer (score 32):

I believe this was mentioned elsewhere, but for completeness, here's [Serre on writing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECQyFzzBHlo).

Comment: My favorite quote from this video (among many great quotes): "I'm sure that if this happened with Bourbaki, some member of Bourbaki, he would tell the other one, "It is because you are stupide and you have not found the correct statement, which would give both of them!""

Answer (score 30):

[Dimensions](http://www.dimensions-math.org/)

[Möbius Transformations Revealed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY&fmt=18)

Comment: Dimensions is great!

Answer (score 23):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SccDUpIPXM0) about Andrew Wiles and the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem is the only time I've seen the real excitement of mathematics presented accurately.

Comment: Thanks! I just watched the video!
I can't even imagine the pressure Wiles got when the proof was Almost there, but just almost, after having announced the result!

Comment: I am unable to watch the video, please help.

Answer (score 22):

'Not Knot' is also a nice vid

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGLPbSMxSUM

Comment: It's not only nice: it's great!

Answer (score 22):

The Newton institute in Cambridge tapes alot (all?) of it's lectures, and they can be found on the Institutes webpage. High quality for videos of lectures.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: http://www.newton.ac.uk/webseminars/

Answer (score 20):

At the accessible end of the scale, [Vi Hart's](http://www.youtube.com/user/Vihart) "doodling in math class" series and subsequent videos are a delight.

Answer (score 19):

MIT's OpenCourseWare has a few math courses up:

http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/web/courses/av/index.htm#Mathematics

Answer (score 15):

The Institute for Advanced Study tapes some of its [lectures](http://video.ias.edu/). They tend to be very good.

Comment: I just found this link a couple of days ago. It is cool indeed :)

Answer (score 15):

GRASP is a new lecture series at the University of Texas at Austin, which is aimed at bringing some of the fundamental concepts and big picture of the GRASP areas (Geometry, Representation, and Some Physics) to a wider audience (the intended target audience are beginning graduate students).

http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/GRASP.html

Comment: they have videos of G. Segal and lurie, it is pretty cool

Answer (score 12):

You probably won't learn much actual math from it, but [One Geometry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3tdimtxqic) is funnier and catchier than a Snoop Dogg parody about 3-manifolds has any right to be.

Comment: Funnier and catchier... yes. And I did learn a bit of Math :)

Answer (score 10):

Along the sphere eversion lines, there is also the energy-minimizing sphere eversion constructed by Rob Kusner.  I think there is a video of it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6cgca4Mmcc, though it isn't labelled as such.

Rob also has written [a paper](http://www.gang.umass.edu/%7Ekusner/other/minimax.pdf) about the history of the minimax eversion.

Answer (score 9):

My personal favorite in Dimensions, that was mentioned before by Gerald Edgar. For a neat and clear exposition the Geom.of 3 manifolds, Poincaré conjecture, etc I recommend [this](http://athome.harvard.edu/threemanifolds/index.html) lecture by C.McMullen. Or Das Schöne denken (hosted at the HIM in Bonn), for a good "glimpse in the world of the mathematician". Jos Leys' mathematical imagery contains some (interesting) videos and (a lot of beautiful) images.

Answer (score 9):

There are Stephen Boyd's lecture videos on convex optimization:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/videos.html

Answer (score 9):

I guess all of John Conway's lectures are great. Some of those can be found here :
http://www.math.princeton.edu/facultypapers/Conway/

Answer (score 7):

The series of videos from [IAS School of Mathematics](http://video.ias.edu/sm)

Answer (score 7):

The [IHES](http://www.ihes.fr/jsp/site/Portal.jsp) also has a lot of [on-line videos](http://www.dailymotion.com/user/Ihes_science/). In particular, I like very much the ones from the "Colloque Grothendieck".

Answer (score 6):

Dror Bar-Natan has begin putting [many of his lectures and talks](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/index.php?title=Dbnvp) online in video format. I'm not claiming that these are the 'best' online maths videos, but they're certainly interesting, and in particular he's come up with some neat tricks to associate publicly editable annotations with particular moments in the video.

Answer (score 6):

Not lecture videos or anything, but the stuff from [Oliver Labs](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=oliver+labs&search_type=&aq=f) is very good for just illustrating geometric stuff, like blowups and dual curves.

Answer (score 6):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned the four-week [workshop at Göttingen](http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/aufzeichnungen/SummerSchool/) on arithmetic geometry in 2006 summer. Almost all of the videos are still available. Wonderful videos.

Answer (score 6):

Videos recorded at IMPA:

http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=download

(some in English, some in Portuguese)

Answer (score 6):

Stoney Brook math videos:

http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/dfest/

http://www.math.sunysb.edu/html/videos.shtml

Comment: This is impressive!!

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread, but this video was recently posted to the Don Davis topology list, and I have to share it. It was created by Niles Johnson at UGA and it illustrates the Hopf fibration.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKotMPGFJYk

Answer (score 5):

This one is quite old but it was fun when I watched a few years ago.
It's about Fermat's Last theorem.

http://www.archive.org/details/fermats_last_theorem

Answer (score 5):

Lots of Lie Theory talks:
http://sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/533438?mediaOffset=20&mediaMax=20&mediaOrder=asc&mediaSort=title#Media

Answer (score 5):

This isn't purely a math video, it's an interview with Peter Woit and it is something of a summary of the main issues discussed on his blog and in his book.  He talks about math vs. physics culture, especially the string theory community.

edit: the link appears to have changed.

https://bigthink.com/u/peterwoit

Discussion here:

[http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=2670](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/wordpress/?p=2670)

Answer (score 5):

[John Stillwell - ET Math: How different could it be?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MV65airaPA) A nice talk given at the SETI Institute.

Answer (score 4):

The "Touching Soap Films" series by Springer. about minimal surfaces. Some excerpts of the video are available here:
http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/polthier/video/Touching/Scenes.html

Answer (score 4):

[This video](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/sciencenow/3210/04.html) is less about mathematics, but about a fascinating mathematician in two bodies who helped saving medieval unicorns - students liked it.

Comment: This is a very cute story! For people who'd prefer a slightly less cryptic description: the video is about two brothers, both professional mathematicians, who helped the Metropolitan Museum of Art construct a high-resolution digital image of a medieval tapestry. The tapestry had been photographed in thirty or so overlapping chunks, but the chunks didn't fit together into a consistent image. With the help of a graduate student, the brothers tracked down the source of the mysterious inconsistencies, and then figured out how to correct them. A nifty application of math---well worth watching!

Answer (score 4):

My good friend  Professor Elvis Zap  has the "Calculus Rap," the "Quantum Gravity Topological Quantum Field Theory Blues," a vid on constructing "Boy's Surface," "Drawing the hypercube (yes he knows there is a line missing in part 1)," A few things on quandles, and a bunch of precalculus and calculus videos. In order to embarrass all involved, he posted the series "Dehn's Dilemma" that was recorded  in Italy last summer.

Answer (score 4):

[Elvis's youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/user/ProfessorElvisZap)

Comment: Hey, that guy looks awfully familiar.

Answer (score 4):

On [this page](http://www.k-3d.org/wiki/Animation_Gallery) of sample animations using the k3d program there's a short animation of a "flower" blooming which is actually the first part of the sphere eversion.

Answer (score 4):

For a course on cluster algebras (by S. Fomin): http://qgm.au.dk/video/mc/cluster/

EDIT: Some graduate short-courses in FCEyN, UBA, Buenos Aires, Argentina:

- J. Harris, Intersection Theory
- R. Hartshorne, Introduction to Deformation Theory
- D. Maclagan, Introduction to Tropical Algebraic Geometry
- P. Beelen, Algebraic Geometric Codes

[Here](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~visita16/ELGA-2011/version/v1/images-en.shtml) are the links to the videos of these 4 lectures.

Answer (score 3):

Among the best math videos can be found here:
http://www.khanacademy.org/

(or the youtube-channel: http://www.youtube.com/khanacademy )

There is everything from counting to solving differential equations with Laplace transforms - nearly 1.000 videos altogether (and the guy is funny :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sir Michael Atiyah: [Beauty in Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dToui7IVwBY).

Answer (score 3):

Ken Ribet's introductory lecture on Serre's modularity conjecture. Useful and quite easy to follow and understand. http://fora.tv/2007/10/25/Kenneth_Ribet_Serre_s_Modularity_Conjecture

Answer (score 3):

NMU(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_University_of_Moscow) and MIAN lectures 2009-2010 (in Russian)

http://erb-files.narod.ru/

Answer (score 3):

[Hitler learns topology](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw)

Answer (score 3):

Timothy Gowers' "[The Importance of Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsIJN4YMZZo)" never fails to instill a sense of purpose in my work, even when I feel I'm doing "useless" mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

Richard Feynman gave the 1964 Messenger Lectures at Cornell University --- this is an endowed lecture series to which a number of famous scholars have been invited, including several physicists.  His lectures were recorded, and Bill Gates bought the rights to them and has provided them to the public for free.

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/tools/tuva/index.html

The content is mostly designed for a general audience, so if you have never learned physics you will learn something.  And if you have studied plenty of physics already, you will be pleased to see the master at work in his prime.  I very much enjoyed watching it.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent (and very lively) overview of basic one-variable calculus: Calculus I in 20 minutes: [Part I](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX_is9LzFSY), [Part II](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9OkFTDG4fY).

Answer (score 2):

The  Abdus Salam International Centre for Theoretical Physics has lots of lectures in mathematics and physics.Some of them are difficult to find in other places(Complex Analysis,Abstract Algebra,Topology,Functional Analysis,Algebraic Geometry..).For the same topic(ex:Complex Analysis)there are lectures by 2 ore more lecturers so you can choose.
http://www.ictp.it/
http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/index07-08.php?activityid=MTH
http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/index08-09.php?activityid=MTH

Answer (score 2):

A nice introduction to representation theory of compact lie groups, sl2(R) and other topics:
http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/sl2/schedule.html

Answer (score 2):

A few talks under the heading "What is ..." (",,," could be "Morse Theory", for example)
given at the Freie Universität Berlin can be found here:

http://www.scivee.tv/user/5216

Answer (score 2):

I found the [Graduate weekend](https://www.math.duke.edu/video/video.html) repository of lectures at the Mathematics Department of Duke's University very entertaining. There is more in the other folders(G.Tian, Langlands, just to name a few   )$\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

The complete [introductory course on Algebraic Geometry by Miles Reid](http://vod.mathnet.or.kr/sub4_1.php?key_s_title=Lectures+on+Basic+Algebraic+Geometry+by+Miles+Reid+(WCU+project)) is very interesting (28 lectures following and extending his own undergraduate book on the subject), and his other set of [lectures on Algebraic Surfaces](http://vod.mathnet.or.kr/sub4_1.php?key_s_title=Lectures+on+Algebraic+Surfaces+by+Miles+Reid+(WCU+project)).

Answer (score 2):

David Cox's lectures in toric varieties at [MSRI](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/scientific/workshops/summer-graduate-workshops/show/-/event/Wm463)

Something really good to end the evening with :)

Answer (score 2):

Marcus du-Sautoy's lecture - [Music of The Prime Numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQFE6dYuQW4), is a very nice popular talk about prime numbers

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, [Rutgers experimental mathematics seminar](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~russell2/expmath/) has over 200 [videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/kgnang) up on youtube. I wish more seminars would do this!

Answer (score 2):

I am quite surprised to see [Dan Freed's lecture of Hodge Conjecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3DOGo_XF2o) has not been mentioned. (Although it is an old thread I believe this should be in here. Before there was a QuickTime video but I am grateful to find that it has been youtubed.)

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the digitized tapes of CBMS Lectures on Probability Theory and Combinatorial by Michael Steele [are online](http://sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/1189351). I heartily recommend them — the style is informal, but educating: there are jokes, juggling lessons, speculations about the stock market, and all of these amidst beautiful mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Two  recent videotaped lectures by Doron Zeilberger.

[The Joy of Dreaming to be Famous (Videotaped lecture), March 1,2012](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/famous.html)

[The Rise and Fall of Astrology and the Future Fall of the so-called Infinity (Videotaped lecture) March 29, 2012](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/astrology.html)

Answer (score 2):

The first [Minerva Lecture](http://www.math.princeton.edu/events/seminars/minerva-lectures/inaugural-minerva-lectures-i-equidistribution) by Jean-Pierre Serre at Princeton in Fall 2012 is online. There were two other lectures, and they did videotape them, but I can't find them online.

Answer (score 2):

Any video on

[Jos Leys "Mathematical Imagery"](http://www.josleys.com/galleries.php?showdate=1)

is a true masterpiece, and has a non-trivial mathematical content...

Answer (score 1):

[The Dot and the Line: A Romance in Lower Mathematics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmSbdvzbOzY)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to think that [my math art](http://www.youtube.com/diproton) is awesome, and start [here](http://www.youtube.com/diproton#p/u/19/FWG5JblSsps).

the mapping behind that video is $(x,y,z)\rightarrow(2*cos(z-y),2*sin(x-z),7*cos(y-x))$, and has a singular Jacobian -- the immediate ramification of which is that there is overlap in the video.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdPrCWr9Ruk&feature=player_embedded#!

is a video made by a student in the school of arichitecture using pov-ray 
is about algebraic surfaces and how they "deform"

there are a few more animations at the following url

http://www.formulas.it/animazioni.php

they are part of on-going project about the visualization 
of mathematics (being developed by group of mathematicians and architects)

Answer (score 1):

Some talks on history by some leading mathematicians (mostly in French):

http://www.archivesaudiovisuelles.fr/FR/_LibraryThemas.asp?thema=541

Answer (score 1):

Searching for a video relating to another question, I found this:
[My Calculus Project](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kklb1J6Ij_U&hd=1)

Answer (score 1):

Documentary about infinite and its implications in mathematics (BBC)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cw-zNRNcF90

As usual, Gregory Chaitin on the history of logic
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLPO-RTFU2o

Another one about logic and artificial intelligence
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nA3m9jgMp3U

Answer (score 1):

All the talks of [Atiyah 80+](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/atiyah80.htm)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/user/njwildberger

Excellent lectures by Norman Wildberger on topics including: Geometry, Algebraic Topology, Linear Algebra, Foundations of Mathematics, and history of Mathematics

Comment: Watched a few Videos. But Wildberger is often trying to push his own views onto students, which he calls "Rational Trigonometry" (as in, Angles should be 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 2$\pi$. This makes the videos hard to watch, as they are not consistent with other books/lectures.

Answer (score 1):

The famous proof of the snake lemma in the 1980's movie *It's my turn* (can be found on utube).

Answer (score 1):

'Selmer Ranks of Elliptic Curves in Families of Quadratic Twists' by Karl Rubin

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/video/default.aspx?id=140581

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSNsgj1OCLA

This video is far better than I expected. Show it to any discrete math course you teach. (With the possible exception of one of those courses that exist only to prepare students for a computer science course they take later.)

Answer (score 0):

The University of New South Wales in Sydney has an eLearning channel on YouTube that contains lectures on a number of topics, including Algebraic Topology, Calculus, and Linear Algebra. Some computing and engineering topics are covered as well.

http://www.youtube.com/user/UNSWelearning#p/p

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one has mentioned that the [Kavli Institute for Theoretical Physics](http://online.kitp.ucsb.edu/online/), the [Simons Center for Geometry and Physics](http://www.scgp.stonybrook.edu/), and the [Perimeter Institute](http://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/) often tape conferences.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will qualify as math exactly, but it's amazing nonetheless. It is a film with Richard Feynman called "Feynman: Take the wold from another point of view". Here is part 1

[Feynman: Take the wold from another point ov view - Part 1/4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsgBtOVzHKI)

Answer (score 0):

I make some maths videos at home,Here is an English video:[Visible Fibre Bundle](http://video.yayun2010.sina.com.cn/v/b/49393046-1215048895.html)

maybe that can help some begginners.

All my maths vedios at [my blog here](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/articlelist_1215048895_12_1.html),thirty courses of communtative algebra and I prepare to make much more in the future,but as you seen,most of them are Chinese(中文）,because I can not say much English.

Answer (score 0):

The amazing patterns that turn up in piece-wise isometries, like circles dancing in a rhomb:

http://vimeo.com/23772888

Comment: Very pretty!!!!   

Answer (score 0):

They filmed the [FRG Conference on Topology and Field Theories](http://nd.edu/~cmnd/conferences/topology/) and put the lectures on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/user/NDdotEDU/videos).

Answer (score 0):

So much maths video in http://nptel.ac.in/ National Programme on Technology Enhanced Learning

Answer (score 0):

I know of some youtube channels with good content. The last two link are not strictly pure math, but still worth a look.

Institut Henri Poincaré:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrKGv5WY5ryaIXEmnxKVxOQ

princetonmathematics
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVKtRsfK1QPyHRP2QupyddQ

Institut des Hautes Études Scientifiques (IHÉS)
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4R1IsRVKs_qlWKTm9pT82Q

StanfordCSTheory:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdZlxxfpEzQWwMvjVQ7gOJw

Simons Institute:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW1C2xOfXsIzPgjXyuhkw9g

Answer (score 0):

[Discrete Integrable Systems](http://sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/533691) at Isaac Newton Institute for Mathematical Sciences

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I have something new to add.  I sometimes make mathematical videos, and I should make more.  Here is one about a 3D diagram that I made of the happy family, in group theory.  There are a lot of other videos on my channel, however, not pertaining to mathematics such as singing and art, but I hope that in the future I will make more mathematical content.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IjnIcECoQ&t=11s

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single video (and sadly there hasn't been any new content in a year!), but [Richard Borcherds's channel](https://www.youtube.com/@richarde.borcherds7998) has some of the best math content I've seen. If I have to pick one I'll go with [this video from his Rings series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuQcj3GdayE0) about Burnside rings and differential operator rings as an illustration of his style; for me, at least, it's a source of excellent insight into fields (*cough*) I know very little about.

Answer (score -1):

The video that I am adding here is a new upload in Youtube.
Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUl28Pjz89M

I have seen many videos on 21-card trick and also read many blogs on it. A very few of them has attempted to explain why this trick works. The ones give the proof, is pretty involved and requires some inclination towards the subject to understand this. But, this video has taken a totally different approach to explain the trick and why it works in a visual way. The approach is easy to understand for anyone. This is a great way of helping students get attracted towards Mathematics.