# Online video of some courses

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Who knows online video of Riemannian Geometry and Commutative Algebra? If you know, please recommend them to me. I am really eager to learn these courses.

Comment: Try the links in this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-math-videos

Answer (score 3):

A number of the video lectures from the "Clay Mathematics Institute 2005 Summer School Ricci Flow, 3 Manifolds And Geometry" are excellent.

http://www.msri.org/web/msri/scientific/workshops/summer-graduate-workshops/show/-/event/Wm367

Answer (score 3):

There is now a great course on Commutative Algebra by Richard Borcherds on Youtube, it follows the book of David Eisenbud :

Commutative Algebra with a view toward Algebraic geometry

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj53rSexSz7vsYt-3rpHPR3HB