# Video lectures of mathematics courses available online for free

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list, mathematics-education, online-resources

It can be difficult to learn mathematics on your own from textbooks, and I often wish universities videotaped their mathematics courses and distributed them for free online. Fortunately, some universities do that (albeit to a very limited extent), and I hope we can compile here a list of all the mathematics courses one can view in their entirety online.

Please only post videos of entire courses; that is, a speaker giving one lecture introducing a subject to the audience should be off-limits, but a sequence of, say, 30 hour-long videos, each of which is a lecture delivered in a class would be very much on-topic.

Comment: Some list can be fetched from the ancient post here:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-math-videos

Comment: +100 if I could. I always wanted to have them in summers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is just a request for collating information that could be found and hosted elsewhere

Comment: I add as comment a collection of 19 videos for the course *Introduction to Loop Quantum Gravity* by professor Carlo Rovelli, it's from the official YouTube chanell  **Quantum Gravity at CPT Marseille**. I don't know these videos of Physics, but I've read several  scientific dissemination books about loop quantum gravity, and this is a topic with very  interesting mathematics. I hope don't bother with my comment, many thanks.

Answer (score 69):

[Ted Chinburg](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/noframes.html) has videos of his lectures for what is going on a 2 year course in algebraic number theory online( direct links to videos: [semester 1](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/620F09/hw-620SchedTab.html), [semester 2](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/620S10/hw-621SchedTab.html), [semester 3](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/720F10/hw-720SchedTab.html), [semester 4](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/721S11/hw-721SchedTab.html)), and from there you can also get lectures from various seminars at Penn.

Also, there's the [MSRI](http://www.msri.org/) database for all the things that go on there, they're all over the website at each program's site.

Comment: Thanks! I edit your post to include direct link to the video list of each semester; I hope you don't mind. 

Comment: Chalk and board presentation... Am I alone who can't stand them anymore, no matter the merit?

Comment: You probably are! I can't stand anything other than chalk and board!

Comment: There are more recent videos on his homepage, but they are quite badly edited. One moment the blackboard is blank, and then all of a sudden it jumps to a board full of a completely unrelated topic! I don't know why the links to past courses have been removed...

Comment: Anyone know the status of these?  I recently pointed a student to these, only to find all of the links were down.

Comment: @CamMcLeman I just attempted to open up the first video of semester one and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: The links on Ted's videos no longer seem to be working in 2020.

Comment: There is this initiative by the Government of India for students in India Swayam(https://swayam.gov.in/) that has more than 2000 courses on various subjects and these are available for free.

Comment: Thank you! Though the videos of the four-semester lectures broke down, some other courses on Prof. Ted Chinburg's website are also useful, especially the one on Iwasawa theory on 2018 Fall!

Answer (score 54):

[77 videos on Category theory](http://www.youtube.com/TheCatsters).

Comment: what order should this stuff be watched in ?

Comment: They have a link for the order on the webpage. Honestly I watched all of their videos but got sick of them pretty quickly. They aren't bad, but they aren't great to watch in one sitting either.

Comment: @William, I find their videos pretty dull and unfocused tbh

Comment: They certainly are not designed to be watched in one sitting!  They are 10 minute, bite-sized videos.  Brent Yorgey's has a [Catsters guide](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/catsters-guide/) where he suggests an order to watch them in.  (He was trying to watch two per week.)

Answer (score 52):

The lecture videos of Introduction to Abstract Algebra, taught by Benedict Gross at Harvard, can be downloaded [here](http://wayback.archive-it.org/3671/20150528171650/https://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra).

Answer (score 48):

Federico Ardila's (full-semester) courses on
[polytopes](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/Polytopes/lectures.html),
[combinatorial commutative algebra](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/CCA/lectures.html),
[Coxeter groups](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/Coxeter/lectures.html),
[combinatorial Hopf algebras](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/Hopf/lectures.html), 
[matroid theory](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/Matroids/lectures.html),
and [enumerative combinatorics](http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/EC/lectures.html). They include lecture videos and lecture notes.
See http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/teaching.html

Now they are also on YouTube here:
[polytopes](http://tinyurl.com/ardilapolytopes),
[combinatorial commutative algebra](http://tinyurl.com/ardilacca),
[Coxeter groups](http://tinyurl.com/ardilacoxeter),
[combinatorial Hopf algebras](http://tinyurl.com/ardilahopf), 
[matroid theory](http://tinyurl.com/ardilamatroids),
and [enumerative combinatorics](http://tinyurl.com/ardilaec).

Comment: the links to the course notes are broken, but the YouTube videos are still there.

Answer (score 35):

Here are some of my favorites :

1. Sidney Coleman's [Quantum Field Theory](https://www.physics.harvard.edu/events/videos/Phys253)
2. Shiraz Minwalla's [String Theory](http://theory.tifr.res.in/%7Eminwalla/)
3. MIT [OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/audio-video-courses/#mathematics)
4. Videos to short courses at some workshops can be found at [IAS](http://video.ias.edu/sm) and [MSRI](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos)

Answer (score 33):

For what it's worth, my own University of Toronto 2009 course on [Algebraic Knot Theory](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/index.php?title=AKT-09).

Comment: Great content, but frankly poor video... so many board diagrams are too blurry to read.

Answer (score 30):

Gilbert Strang's [course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/) on Linear Algebra at MIT.

Answer (score 27):

[Algebraic topology](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=41FDABC6AA085E78) by Prof. N J Wildberger of the School of Mathematics and Statistics, UNSW

Comment: I'd steer clear of these. Besides his nontraditional views, they're just not very good (they're elementary, not really very rigorous, and due to the above don't cover the same material as you'd see in a normal treatment of the material).

Comment: Being nontraditional isn't a bad thing. He clearly explains his approach and covers interesting, engaging content. I also don't think that an undergraduate algebraic topology course at the level he is going for (covering in fact a large chunk of material) needs to have ever thing detailed in a grad style level of rigor. Very few undergrads get most of the material he introduces.

Answer (score 24):

[The Fourier Transform and Its Applications](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB24BC7956EE040CD), taught by Brad Osgood at Stanford. Lecture notes [here](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/book-fall-07.pdf).

Answer (score 23):

Miles Reid's lectures on [Algebraic Geometry](http://www.mathnet.or.kr/new_VOD/sub1.php?key_s_title=Lectures+on+Basic+Algebraic+Geometry+by+Miles+Reid+%28WCU+project%29) and [Algebraic Surfaces](http://vod.mathnet.or.kr/sub1.php?key_s_title=Lectures+on+Algebraic+Surfaces+by+Miles+Reid+%28WCU+project%29).

Comment: Are they as much filled with side blows as his book?

Comment: I like very much his books (including side blows). The lectures are witty..

Comment: how do I view these lectures? I'm unable to open them.


Comment: You can watch them with Windows Media Player.

Comment: thanks. can one download?

Comment: What is a side blow?

Comment: The site seems down.

Answer (score 20):

At my YouTube site [Insights into Mathematics](http://www.youtube.com/user/njwildberger?feature=mhee). I have playlists on

Rational Trigonometry

Linear Algebra

Math Foundations

History of Mathematics

Universal Hyperbolic Geometry

Algebraic Topology (this was mentioned above)

Elementary Mathematics (K-6)

Answer (score 17):

Three courses by Stephen Boyd at Stanford: [Introduction to Linear Dynamical Systems](http://stanford.edu/class/ee363/), [Convex Optimization I](http://stanford.edu/class/ee364a/), and [Convex Optimization II](http://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/videos.html).

Comment: There are no videos on that page

Answer (score 17):

[Geometric Representation Theory Seminar - Fall 2007](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-fall2007/) by John Baez and James Dolan

> This fall, our seminar is tackling geometric representation theory — the marvelous borderland where geometry, groupoid theory and logic merge into a single subject. The seminar is jointly run by John Baez and James Dolan. Besides explaining well-known stuff, we'll report on research we've done with Todd Trimble over the last few years.

Comment: Is anyone else having trouble getting audio from the videos? I'm pretty sure that the audio worked just fine for me back in '07 when I originally watched these, but now I don't hear anything. I tried streaming the videos in Chrome, in Firefox, downloading and opening with the standalone QuickTime application, as well as opening with VLC. The video shows up just fine but no audio from any of them. Running Windows 7.

Answer (score 17):

This might not fulfill the requirements of being a mathematics course, but I think that it is close enough. In 2006 the Clay Mathematics Institute hosted a [Summer School in Arithmetic Geometry](http://www.claymath.org/library/proceedings/cmip08c.pdf). The [videos](http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/aufzeichnungen/SummerSchool/) are great if you have a solid foundation in algebraic geometry already and wish to continue in the direction of arithmetic geometry .

Answer (score 17):

[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/category/math)  offers not just the videos, but entire courses: I'm currently following Probabilistic Graphical Models, which has weekly exercises and programming projects (which are marked by an autograder), plus community discussion boards and a wiki for collaborating with other students pursuing the course at the same time. Although you could presumably just create an account towards the end of term, archive off all the videos and then watch them at your leisure rather than trying to match the (reasonably demanding) schedule.

Comment: I took a Cryptography course there and it was good!
Also, it seems like it is growing quite fast with more and more courses added.
Definitely recommended to take a look.

Answer (score 17):

[David Gay](http://euclidlab.org/david-gay/) gave a graduate course on Morse Theory at the University of Georgia this spring and the videos are compiled together in a YouTube playlist at [Morse Theory: UGA 2012](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL48612E5AEB587038). Notes for his course are also online on [the course website.](http://euclidlab.org/blogs/morse-and-cerf-theory)

Answer (score 16):

Carmen Rovi's [DailyMotion website](http://www.dailymotion.com/Carmen_Rovi) has 160+ videos on the topology of manifolds in general, and surgery theory in particular, of lectures either given at the University of Edinburgh or at conferences elsewhere. Some of the lectures are courses, and some are one-offs. The November 2012 Edinburgh [course of 12 lectures](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/kirby.htm) by Rob Kirby on high-dimensional manifold topology is a particular highlight.

Answer (score 14):

[Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/), taught at MIT by Charles Leiserson and Erik Demaine.

Answer (score 14):

Graduate course on [Computational Complexity and Quantum Compuation](http://www.sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/545358) given at Cambridge University by Timothy Gowers.

Answer (score 14):

Richard E. Borcherds has posted videos for courses on group theory, commutative algebra, classical Algebraic geometry and scheme theoretic algebraic geometry.

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIyDqfi_cbkp-RU20aBF-MQ)

Connecticut summer school in number theory (CTNT) has short courses on different topics, like modular forms, elliptic curves, p-adic numbers, sieve methods, etc.

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmG6gHgD8JaEZVxuHWJijGQ)

Answer (score 13):

Plenty of short courses given at workshops can be found in the Newton Institute archive at newton.cam.ac.uk.

Here is the link: http://www.newton.ac.uk/webseminars/

Answer (score 13):

Multivariable Calculus by Edward Frenkel at Berkeley:

http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=07CF868151394FE3

Answer (score 12):

MIT's Open Courseware is a very good source of this http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm.

I personally recommend the differential equations course they have.

Answer (score 11):

A course on [Lie groups](http://webmovies.science.uu.nl/WISM414/) taught by Erik van den Ban at Utrecht University.

The parent directory contains a few more bachelor level courses, but these are in Dutch.

Answer (score 10):

The entire master course at ICTP:

http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/index2.php?activityid=MTH

Answer (score 10):

### A great collection of combinatorics videos

## [Igor Pak’s Collection of Combinatorics Videos](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/lectures/Math-Videos/comb-videos.htm)

Answer (score 9):

Here is an ongoing series of videos covering [Point-Set Topology](http://www.youtube.com/user/ThoughtSpaceZero#grid/user/F94A6F65866F3F31) that is planned to continue indefinitely.

Comment: Not going to continue?

Answer (score 9):

[Eleven lectures](http://www.youtube.com/user/amriprasad#grid/user/FE2F2CDA55A9EBB6) by Amritanshu Prasad on representation theory, the first two on generalities, the next five deal with representations of symmetric groups in the semisimple case, going up to the calculation of character values using Frobenius' formula. The next two deal with polynomial representations of GL(m). The last two are on the hook-length formula and Frobenius's characteristic function respectively. Assignments and notes are available on the [course website](http://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/rt11/) for the first seven lectures.

This content forms the bulk of a book titled "[Representation Theory: A Combinatorial Viewpoint](http://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/rtcv/)" (Cambridge University Press, 2015) by the lecturer.

Answer (score 9):

[The Eilenberg Lectures at Columbia.](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~staff/EilenbergVideos/index.html)  So far, the topics have been:

- Benedict Gross, on number theory and representation theory
- Edward Frenkel, on Langlands program and quantum field theory
- Sergiu Klainerman, on the mathematical theory of general relativity

Answer (score 7):

Lectures on Real Analysis, from Bilkent University (Assoc. Prof. Dr. Alexandre Gontcharov): http://video.bilkent.edu.tr/regenerated_pages/Mathematics_ms.html

Comment: Link is now broken, unfortunately.

Comment: @YiFan Just updated: http://video.bilkent.edu.tr/regenerated_pages/Mathematics_ms.html

Answer (score 7):

[MSRI's online videos](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos). These do not consist of courses, but each semester is themed so the videos offer good exposure to many areas of current research.

Comment: This duplicates part of Verma (on the other hand, Hill had a better MSRI link at first). What should I do...?

Answer (score 7):

[Master Class on Wall-Crossing](http://qgm.au.dk/video/mc/wall-crossing/). Lectures given by Maxim Kontsevich.

Answer (score 7):

A [real analysis](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqEyWLGvvdw&feature=results_main&playnext=1&list=PLBC60083951BC3023) course from Harvey Mudd College. An early course for math majors, so it also covers a bit of good proof writing techniques, induction proofs, logic, etc.

(Disclaimer: Filmed by me. So you know who to blame for the bad camera work.)

Answer (score 7):

The courses of the summer school **Poisson 2012** (that took place in Utrecht), as well as lectures of the conference that followed, are available online: http://www.youtube.com/user/poissonutrecht

The courses are:

- [Poisson and Symplectic Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Flat Connections](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYDi1NTJ930), by Anton Alekseev
- [Poisson Geometry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYSE7p9fRBE), by Rui Loja Fernandes
- [Lie Groupoids and Multiplicative Structures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yai8BIUfTuY), by Henrique Bursztyn
- [Cluster Algebras and Compatible Poisson Structures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uiNqQIOzK4), by Michael Gekhtman

Answer (score 7):

There are many good quality math lectures (mostly in Russian but sometimes in English)  http://www.lektorium.tv/  they are grouped by courses (for example http://www.lektorium.tv/course/?id=22876)

Answer (score 7):

I am teaching a course on "Free Probability Theory" this term (winter term 2018/19). The videos will appear progressively [here](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/speicher/web_video/freeprobws1819/free_prob_ws1819.html).

Comment: Dear Professor Roland Speicher, I started watching your Free Probability Theory's lecture recently. May I know whether there is any lecture notes for your course so that I can review after class? Thanks.

Comment: @Idonknow The lectures are based on my two monographs on this subject, for which you can find pdf files on my homepage (https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/speicher/speicher_publikationenE.html)

Comment: @Idonknow There are now also scans of my handwritten notes for the course available at https://rolandspeicher.com/lectures/fpt1819/

Comment: Dear Professor Roland, thanks for the updates.

Answer (score 6):

[Sets, Counting, and Probability](http://wayback.archive-it.org/3671/20150528171638/https://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/sets-counting-probability), taught by Paul Bamberg at Harvard.

Answer (score 6):

A bit borderline since its only nine lectures, but a mini course on [Additive Combinatorics](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/theory/index.php/Main/AdditiveCombinatoricsMinicourse) taught at IAS by Boaz Barak, Luca Trevisan, and Avi Wigderson.

Comment: Link is now broken

Answer (score 6):

The San Francisco State University hosts large number of course videos on various subjects
including:

$\cdot$42 videos on Coxeter Groups

$\cdot$41 videos on Discrete Geometry

$\cdot$18 on Dynamical Systems

$\cdot$16 on Lie Algebras

$\cdot$43 on Matroid Theory

$\cdot$28 on Real Analysis I and II $\ldots$

All you need to do is click on the drop down menu ["List all courses"](http://math.sfsu.edu/courseofferings.php).

Comment: The link seems to be broken, but the author (last seen over 3 years ago) might have meant to link here: http://math.sfsu.edu/courseofferings.php

Comment: I am not seeing any video links on the website, but I suspect a few of these are by Federico Ardila and can be found on YouTube by searching for the author and the name of the course.

Answer (score 6):

Twenty-four lectures from [a course on algebraic combinatorics](http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/192/topics.html), taught by James Propp.

Answer (score 5):

Search [iTunesU](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/) for "Mathematics": It turns up *many* courses (I couldn't see how to count them easily), including the Gilbert Strang course already mentioned.

Comment: Right, I am aware that many of these would already be on iTunesU. However, many are not, and I was thinking it would quite useful to have all of them in one place. 

Answer (score 5):

[Differential Equations](http://videolectures.net/mit1803s06_differential_equations/), taught by Arthur Mattuck at MIT.

Comment: That's *Arthur* Mattuck. 

Answer (score 5):

Might as well plug my own course on Diophantine Geometry. It's in Portuguese, so that will restrict the audience a bit, but I am having fun and it's nearly finished (last class on Nov 8th 2011). IMPA has a bunch of other videos as well, just follow the links.

http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-doutorado-2011-geometria-diofantina

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend those from [Simon's Center for Geometry and Physics](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/). Here is a [list of all workshops](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/scientific/workshops) at SCGP.

Videos from all of their workshops are available online.  Here are all talks from [Random Tilings Workshop](http://scgp.stonybrook.edu/archives/3449) last February.

Answer (score 5):

If it's not too gauche to plug my own course at CMU,

23 lectures on Analysis of Boolean Functions (one lecture by John Wright):

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/aobf12/

Answer (score 5):

The videos of Mike Freedman lectures on the topology of 4-manifolds, broadcasted from UC Santa Barbara: [Freedman's Lectures](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/4436)

Also other videos on 4-manifolds and related topics given at MPIM during the 4-manifold semester in 2013: [MPIM lectures](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/4617)

Answer (score 4):

My alma mater, the University of Colorado at Colorado Springs, has a video course archive on some subjects (mostly undergraduate). These include

Calculus I, II, III

Differential Equations (undergrad and grad)

Linear algebra (undergrad and grad)

Discrete Math (undergrad)

Algebra (elementary and abstract)

Analysis (Real, Functional, but no Complex)

Statistics (graduate)

Geometry (mostly Euclidean)

There are several more.

For each class here, the entire semester was recorded.
To download the videos, you have to create an account, which merely requires a name and email address.

Here's the webpage:
https://www.uccs.edu/math/vidarchive.html

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Thirty lectures from the course [Wavelet Theory](http://www.norbertwiener.umd.edu/Education/wavelets/index.html) given at the University of Maryland by John Benedetto.

Answer (score 4):

LMS Durham Symposia have archive of videos online which can be found at http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/events/Meetings/LMS/

For example, 2009 conference on model theory of fields has videos of the talks by Hrushovski, Kazhdan, Macintyre and Zilber, among the others.

Answer (score 4):

Here a summer school on representation theory for $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$:

http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/sl2/

Clay Mathematics Institute Summer School 2006 on "Arithmetic geometry":

http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/aufzeichnungen/SummerSchool/

Algebraic Quantum Field Theory - the first 50 Years

http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/aufzeichnungen/AQFT50/

Comment: Last two links now broken

Comment: Seem to have been migrated to youtube.

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhsb6tmzSpizK_MHYhWif0kOVj4A0MgJX&si=u5QK8IbhI1fkixtZ

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLelIK3uylPMEC08zw7TS7s1BSISlgkgPX&si=r_CcMBx0nO-LgsjB

Answer (score 4):

nice videos about [Quantum Mechanics](https://podcasts.ox.ac.uk/series/quantum-mechanics) (By J.J.Binney -Oxford),  total 27 videos with about 1 hour duration, and [QFT](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qftvids.html) (By David Tong - Cambridge). Those videos about QM are really great here.

Answer (score 4):

[Thematic Program on Topology and Field Theories](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC80A29806A2EA6B1A), Summer 2012, 34 Lectures.

Answer (score 4):

Joyal's mini-course on topos theory at IHÉS:

[Clicky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro8KoFFdtS4&list=PLrQZHQg-9D-bsxfNIohmi-FhcajrkXUWA)

Answer (score 4):

The [Arizona Winter School](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/index.html) short course videos have been very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the very stimulating lectures by prof Alan Huckleberry at Bremen;

[Differential geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BST6YygE1mE&list=PLWy-AYZriyMFFGWIhY7ZU3gZLslh8QCmC)

[Complex Analytic and Algebraic Geometry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxsUhWj_7UY&list=PLWy-AYZriyMGZjZQ7I8kYhZhtlUzFcWcz)

[Foundations of Mathematical Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3-0cRgPGRY&list=PLWy-AYZriyMHd7I6laIwhwG40-HP5r6oC)

Answer (score 4):

1. [30 lectures on Lie Groups, Representation theory and Symmetric Spaces by Wolfgang Ziller, UPenn](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBRXUqOeXKbVzgB1Sm0v0_4uThoPKrlbT)
2. [27 lectures on Algebraic Topology by Pierre Albin, University of Illinois](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpRLWqLFLVTCL15U6N3o35g4uhMSBVA2b)
3. [36 lectures on Topology & Geometry by Dr Tadashi Tokieda](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTBqohhFNBE_09L0i-lf3fYXF5woAbrzJ)
4. [28 lectures on Differential manifolds and Lie groups (Lectures on Geometrical Anatomy of Theoretical Physics) by Frederic P Schuller](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic)
5. [50 lectures on Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGAnmvB9m7zOBVCZBUUmSinFV0wEir2Vw)
6. [15 lectures on Ricci Flow by Bennett Chow at MSRI](https://www.msri.org/people/11428)

Answer (score 3):

Two courses by Gilbert Strang: [Computational Science and Engineering I](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-085-computational-science-and-engineering-i-fall-2008/video-lectures/) and [Mathematical Methods for Engineers II](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/video-lectures/).

Answer (score 3):

David Forney's course on [Coding Theory](http://videolectures.net/mit6451s05_principles_digital_communication/) at MIT.

Answer (score 3):

The University of South Florida has a whole series of lectures devoted to numerical methods here: http://numericalmethods.eng.usf.edu/videos/

Answer (score 3):

A master course by Benoit Fresse on [operads and Grothendieck-Teichmüller groups](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~operads/LilleCourse2012-Synopsis.html) (in french), at Université Lille 1, given this semester (Winter 2012).
The course has a really nice and complete introduction to the subject. The principal reference is a [preprint](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~operads/pub/OperadGT-January2012Preprint.pdf) (in english) writed by Fresse.

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Ng at Stanford offers [videos of various courses](http://videolectures.net/andrew_ng/).

Answer (score 3):

A [Computability Theory](http://kasterma.net/teach.html) course by Bart Kastermans.  These lectures followed Robert Soare's [new book](http://www.people.cs.uchicago.edu/~soare/cta/), which is not yet published, so they are temporarily behind a password; however, Bart's website indicates that the passwords are available upon request. (In any case they will be open to the public eventually, I think.)

Answer (score 3):

My rather standard course on ordinary differential equations, at http://drorbn.net/index.php?title=12-267.

Answer (score 3):

The YouTube channel of The Institute of Mathematical Sciences, Chennai has several such courses, such as "Effective methods in Diophantine Analysis" by Yuri Bilu, "Soergel modules and Kazhdan-Lusztig theory" by Ben Elias, a course on von Neumann algebras by Sunder, Lie groups by Raghunathan and many more:

http://www.youtube.com/user/matsciencechannel/playlists

Answer (score 3):

The Hausdorff Center for Mathematics in Bonn has a lot of videos online on their [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2F-j2KMho0zVWIPFKWoXoA).

Answer (score 3):

For elementary courses, say up to first year undergraduate or so, [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) has a wide range of courses on maths (some of which are listed under computer science or physics).

For graduate courses, several answers have mentioned MSRI and/or the Hausdorff institute but [the Fields Institute video archive](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive/) deserves a mention as well. The archive does no go back very far, but there are some excellent courses at various levels. (Search for the word "course" on the linked page).

Answer (score 3):

I have recorded lecture series on

- [Random Matrices](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY11JnnnTUCZSUk2xnombjwfg6z3-okP5)
- [Mathematical Aspects of Quantum Mechanics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY11JnnnTUCZOSWtH2fcaMrBDmm4d0GvR)
- [High Dimensional Analysis: Random Matrices and Machine Learning](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY11JnnnTUCabY4nc0hKptrd5qEWtLoo2)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of links to various pages filled with online video lectures [here](http://www.ims.cuhk.edu.hk/geometry/).

Go to "Links" on the left hand side.

Some of the links are broken or out of date, but there's still a ton of good stuff here.

Comment: Here is the direct link:

http://www.ims.cuhk.edu.hk/geometry/links.htm

Comment: Very good collection, most of geometry related links in other answers can be found here in one place

Answer (score 2):

Very, very introductory lectures in complex analysis: http://adamglesserf09math481.wordpress.com/page/3/

Answer (score 2):

Eight recent lectures by Emmanuel Candes on compressed sensing are linked to from here: http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/INI/iniw04p.html

More generally, the Newton Institute has been making a large archive of talks available.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to know Italian, on [Massimo Gobbino's home page](http://users.dma.unipi.it/gobbino/Home_Page/ArchivioDidattico.html) there are videos (tablet pc screencasts + audio) of several courses (Calculus I and II for engineers, honors calculus/analysis) and lots of high-school Math Olympiad training material.

Highly recommended: I find tablet screencasts an excellent medium, and on top of that Massimo is a great teacher.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a summer school on Berkovich spaces

http://www.diffusion.ens.fr/index.php?res=cycles&idcycle=490

(there are more courses at http://www.diffusion.ens.fr/ but unfortunately they are not broken into categories; one has to fish for mathematical courses more or less via manual search)

The following links lead to lectures in Russian.

http://bogomolov-lab.ru/SHKOLA/courses.html

a summer school for undergraduates (topics include number theory, metric geometry, anabelian geometry)

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/presentation.phtml?&option_lang=eng

has a huge collection of videos, including recordings of summer school courses both for undergraduates and graduates.

http://www.lektorium.tv/ is an example of a similar effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good series of video lectures from IIT Kharagpur:

https://nptel.ac.in/courses/122104017/

Answer (score 2):

This collection has a mixture of French and English, but [here](http://video.upmc.fr/differe.php?collec=S_C_galois_2011) you can find videos given at the Bicentennial of the Birth of Evariste Galois (Bicentennaire de la naissance d'Evariste Galois) at the Institut Henri Poincaré in Paris.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~joseph/orbits/) you find the videos of the conference "Orbits, Primitive Ideals and Quantum Groups", Weizmann Institute, Israel.

The videos are about:

1. Finite W-algebras, by I. Losev
2. Adapted pairs in a biparabolic subalgebra, by F. Fauquant-Millet
3. Hopf Algebra and Root Systems, by H-J Schneider
4. Quiver Grassmannians, by M. Reineke
5. Quantum quasi-Shuffles, by M. Rosso

Answer (score 2):

Steven Miller's ongoing lectures on complex analysis are very stimulating

http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ_iaWQx0NpVVKvfT9tuCOg http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/

Answer (score 2):

*Partially orderdered sets* course by William T. Trotter: http://posets.tcs.uj.edu.pl/archive/.

Answer (score 2):

The courses of the summer school **Poisson 2016** (that took place in Geneva) are available online.

The courses are:

- **Cohomological methods in field theory: BV, BFV and BRST**, by Giovanni Felder
  (video: [lectures 1 and 2](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95557), [lecture 3](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95561), [lecture 4](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95565)),
- **Introduction to Poisson geometry and Lie algebroids** by Eckhard Meinrenken
  (video: [lecture 1](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95551), [lecture 2](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95558), [lecture 3](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95563), [lecture 4](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95613))
- **Integrable systems, symmetries and quantization** by San Vu Ngoc and Daniele Sepe
  (video: [lecture 1](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95552), [lecture 2](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95559), [lecture 3](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95614), [lecture 4](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95616))
- **Algebraic methods in holomorphic Poisson geometry** by Brent Pym
  (video: [lecture 1](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95560), [lecture 2](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95564), [lecture 3](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95615), [lecture 4](https://mediaserver.unige.ch/play/95617)).

Even the lectures of the conference **Poisson 2016** (that took place in Zurich) are available [online](http://www.video.ethz.ch/conferences/2016/poisson.html).

Answer (score 2):

CIRM has a collection of video courses called [CARMIN.TV](https://library.cirm-math.fr/)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of good math courses available [here](http://videos.math.sharif.ir/).

Answer (score 2):

My [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0Jj0V0o0i7RWfwDgRwe4rg) on exterior differential systems and the lecture [notes](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=2F932C4FCBB9B86BEF31A43BBDEEE5AE).

Answer (score 2):

1. Here are video lectures from Taiwan Mathematics School; some of them were delivered in Mandarin: https://sites.google.com/view/tms-home/media-archive?authuser=0
2. The following courses (all in Mandarin) were taught by Professor Chen-Yu Chi at National Taiwan University:

- [Calculus 1](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVJXJebpO4PhAc21JW-cYbzT3sq4s7Qg8) & [Calculus 2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLil-R4o6jmGihq7XzdNzb0d5hHqEJbr6L). The topics in these courses are more like "advance calculus", not the usual calculus content.
- [Analysis 1](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLil-R4o6jmGhUqtKbZf0LIFKd-xN__g_M) & [Analysis 2](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLil-R4o6jmGhkuZPmKL_A5Y7N4HOsa1nX). The topics include complex analysis, de Rham cohomology, functional analysis, Lebesgue integral, smooth manifold, measure theory, ODE, singular homology, topology.
- [Algebraic Topology](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLp24IEwWwtLJBhl1TvYjXF1-17q5lDpd3). The main textbook is *Algebraic Topology* by Edwin H. Spanier.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found the YouTube channel of the university of Uppsala (Uppsala Algebra : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPWnhR29VHTAk7rZUEDQdDQ/playlists)

It contains mostly courses by Walter Mazorchuk on representation theory of finite groups, Lie algebras and the category O (and on linear algebra which if of less interest for me) and a course on commutative algebra and algebraic geometry by Seidon Alsaody.

I mostly watched the courses by W. Mazorchuk and they are very good.

Answer (score 2):

A [series of lectures on symmetric functions, Macdonald polynomials and double affine Hecke algebras](https://sites.google.com/view/wmp-2021/notesvideos) (videos and notes) organised in 2021 by R Venkatesh of the Indian Institute of Science; see also its [youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQXtaLhI1-1qNWb_UslCDx5Fx3XZKrAHK), the [syllabus](https://sites.google.com/view/wmp-2021/syllabus), and the ensuing [conference on applications of Macdonald polynomials](https://sites.google.com/view/camp-iisc-2021/home?authuser=0) (videos and slides)

Answer (score 1):

the link by  [Elohemahab Solomon some lectures on lie algebra](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search.php?activityid=HEP&course=Lie_Groups_and_Lie_Algebras)

Comment: @Neeraj, you can find them here:http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search.php?activityid=HEP&course=Lie_Groups_and_Lie_Algebras

Answer (score 1):

All Master Classes given at QGM and the previous CTQM are online here: http://qgm.au.dk/video/ and here: http://www.ctqm.au.dk/news/special_events.html.

It is quite an extensive list of 17 Master Classes in total. The courses are on a variety of different subjects, given by among others Maxim Kontsevich, Nicolai Reshetikhin, Nigel Hitchin, Vaughan Jones, Tom Mrowka, Gregor Masbaum, Dylan Thurston, Robert Penner and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good resource of video lectures conducted by IIT's & IISc's:

[1](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses.php?disciplineId=111)

There is also a YouTube channel:

[2](http://www.youtube.com/user/nptelhrd)

Answer (score 1):

A one semester [introductory course to infinite-dimensional differential geometry (Lie groups and Riemannian geometry)](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwDBpozLuH8Pcto54ul5GM2LNJNIuc446) can be found here

Answer (score 1):

My course lecture videos:

- [Introductory linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOAf1ViVP13jmawPabxnAa00YFIetVqbd) (44 videos on YouTube, lecture notes in the video descriptions)
- [Advanced linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOAf1ViVP13jdhvy-wVS7aR02xnDxueuL) (42 videos on YouTube, lecture notes in the video descriptions)

Answer (score 1):

My videos about the application of mathematics in physics are in

https://www.aparat.com/Meisami67

Also there are videos which contain intriguing short questions and their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Mini-course on ["FROBENIUS MANIFOLDS, IRREGULAR SINGULARITIES, AND
ISOMONODROMY DEFORMATIONS"](https://irregular.rd.ciencias.ulisboa.pt/frobenius-manifolds-irregular-singularities-and-isomonodromy-deformations/),

The course will consist of 5 lectures, which will be shown live on
YouTube, at the url shown below (where the lectures will stay available
for a later view).

1)[Introduction to Frobenius manifolds](https://youtu.be/ngwB7kV1mRo)

2)[Examples of Frobenius manifolds](https://youtu.be/euu3ilCPTEE)

3)Analytic theory of Frobenius manifolds -

[I](https://youtu.be/tBOTQZcRKuw)

[II](https://youtu.be/VyvXIaBqhWY)

4)[Some recent results and work in progress](https://youtu.be/ale6HrNrq6s)