# Video lectures for algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, online-resources

Are there any good video lectures for studying algebraic geometry?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free At least one answer also links to a algebraic geometry lecture.

Comment: 1) What flavor of algebraic geometry? 2) How much depth do you need?

Comment: Something similar to that covered in Hartshorne.

Comment: Great question! I would love to know as many answers as possible to it

Comment: @Martin: Quite right. I came here to post the link to Miles Reid's lectures http://www.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/AGvid.html but I see it's already there.


Comment: this might be good http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/MOS/seminars/index.html

Comment: does anyone know how to download Miles Reid Video lectures from vod.mathnet? no mms downloader seems to work for me. Any successful attempts?

Comment: You can use mplayer with the option -dumpstream. Here is an example to download one of the videos linked here: mplayer -dumpstream  http://strato.impa.br/videos/27_CBM/27CBM_300709_03.avi (mplayer will save the video in the file stream.dump).

Comment: @Anonymous, open the .asx file with wordpad and locate a .wmv url. Then download this file with your favourite download manager if it doesn't time out.

Comment: I am not able too see the videos of Reid from the website. Any help

Comment: You can use Get ASF Stream.

Comment: Anyone able to view these at another location online?

Comment: @TZE, I've done that but what I get is a file with wmv extenstion that give  a live stream . I did not get a link to download it.

Comment: For Real Algebraic Geometry: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSGoR6RPC58&list=PLbQ93L5pV-a_RRwdEgGungHn5rN43BGe7
Accompanying lecture notes available in arXiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.04211.pdf

Answer (score 23):

Some graduate short-courses in FCEyN, UBA, Buenos Aires, Argentina:

- J. Harris, Intersection Theory
- R. Hartshorne, Introduction to Deformation Theory
- D. Maclagan, Introduction to Tropical Algebraic Geometry
- P. Beelen, Algebraic Geometric Codes

[Here](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~visita16/ELGA-2011/version/v1/images-en.shtml) are the links to the videos of these 4 lectures. Also available in [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaP4UdjleezecVaXBa7spkw) of the Universidad de Buenos Aires.

Comment: I was at Harris' lectures and can recommend them for anyone interested in an introduction to intersection theory. They are very motivated, example driven, and simply outstanding.

Comment: Harris' lectures are really great indeed...

Answer (score 16):

You haven't been very precise about what you want ; let me still suggest the "video homepage" of the [IHES](http://www.dailymotion.com/Ihes_science), where you'll find quality videos about various aspects of algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 12):

Among the long list of lectures recorded every year in [ICTP](http://www.ictp.it/research/math.aspx), here are 40 lectures each year by [Lothar Goettsche](http://users.ictp.it/~gottsche/) on Algebraic Geometry:

[2007/08 Algebraic Geometry Course in Mathematics](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search07-08.php?activityid=MTH&course=Algebraic_Geometry)

[2008/09 Algebraic Geometry Course in Mathematics](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search08-09.php?activityid=MTH&course=Algebraic_Geometry)

[2009/10 Algebraic Geometry Course in Mathematics](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search09-10.php?activityid=MTH&course=Algebraic_Geometry)

[2010/11 Algebraic Geometry Course in Mathematics](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search10-11.php?activityid=MTH&course=Algebraic_Geometry)

Comment: I tried to watch the video. The sound is  good, but the picture is terrible, completely impossible to see what is written on the board. Can you really see what is in this lecture? (maybe I am missing something, but I tried all three formats proposed on the website)

Comment: @aglearner: A high-res zoom can be seen on the right of the low-res video. It is updated every few seconds.

Comment: @aglearner, it is recommended that you watch the videos on-line(with out downloading) as a high-res picture of the board is shot every 15 seconds and synchronized with the lecture video.

Comment: What is the depth? Hartshorne? Did anyone try these lectures?

Answer (score 12):

This post is to link some videos from [IMPA](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=download), Brazil.

Colóquio Brasileiro de Matemática:

- [Algebraic Curves and their Moduli, Enrico Arbarello](http://strato.impa.br/videos/25_CBM/e_arbarello.wmv)
- [Modern enumerative geometry, Rahul Pandharipande](http://strato.impa.br/videos/26_CBM/Plenaria-310707-RahulPandharipande.avi)
- [On the classification of algebraic space curves, Robin Hartshorne](http://strato.impa.br/videos/27_CBM/27CBM_290709_03.avi)
- [Convex Algebraic Geometry - Bernd Sturmfels](http://strato.impa.br/videos/27_CBM/27CBM_300709_03.avi)

IMPA 50 Anos:

- [Abel's theorem in its classical, modern and post-modern forms, Phillip Griffiths](http://strato.impa.br/videos/50ANOS/griffiths.wmv)

---

The webpage of the [Brazil-France School and Workshop on Algebraic Geometry](http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=brazil-france-school-and-workshop-on-algebraic-geometry) contains links to the following videos:

Mini-courses:

- Introduction to algebraic groups, Bertrand Rémy
- Frobenius splitting, Stéphane Druel
- Rational curves on algebraic varieties, Carolina Araujo
- Introduction to Berkovich geometry, Amaury Thuillier
- Rational points and rational curves, Emmanuel Peyre
- Geometric Invariant Theory, Eduardo Esteves

Talks:

- Bergman kernels and applications, Mihai Paun
- Exponential rarefaction of real curves with many components, Jean-Yves Welschinger
- Berkovich geometry and Satake compactifications, Bertrand Rémy
- Counting, Tightness and (non arch.) Symmetric spaces, Rodolphe Richard
- On recursive towers of curves over finite fields, Arnaldo Garcia

Comment: The IMPA links are broken.

Answer (score 9):

There is now an outstanding YouTube channel by Richard Borcherds with courses on Algebraic geometry (introduction), Schemes, Commutative algebra.

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIyDqfi_cbkp-RU20aBF-MQ

I watched all the videos so far (>200) and found all them really good, hope that there will be many more new videos on this channel.

Answer (score 8):

If you understand Russian, then you can listen to lectures of Orlov and Kuznetsov that are given here:

http://erb-files.narod.ru/

Orlov is giving lectures on Hartshorne's level, these are very good lectures. I hope very much that your question will get more answers.

**Added.** It turns out that on the same website there is a course called "Algebra 3, 2010", it is by Loktev. This course can be seen as an introductory course to algebraic geometry (treating Bezout's theorem, Nullstellensatz and many other things). I find this course really well done and very well motivated. (of course this is in Russian).

Answer (score 8):

The following lectures by Caucher Birkar provide a great introduction to birational geometry and its most recent developments:

http://www.dailymotion.com/playlist/x1j6g1_Sciences_Maths_Paris_birational-geometry/1#video=xgw1sp

Answer (score 6):

The conference [Algebraic Geometry Northeastern Series (AGNES)](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/), Stony Brook 2011.

These videos are included:

- [Eyal Markman, Morrison's movable cone conjecture for irreducible holomorphic symplectic varieties](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=01-Markman)
- [Patrick Brosnan, Degenerations of Mixed Hodge Structure from a Tannakian viewpoint](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=02-Brosnan)
- [Valery Alexeev, Geometric meaning of toroidal compactifications of moduli spaces](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=03-Alexeev)
- [Joe Harris, Rationality of Cubic Fourfolds](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=04-Harris)
- [Roya Beheshti, Spaces of rational curves on general hypersurfaces](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=05-Beheshti)
- [Dawei Chen, Flat surfaces, moduli of differentials and Teichmueller curves](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=06-Chen)
- [Mircea Mustaţă, The non-nef locus in positive characteristic](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=07-Mustata)
- [Dan Abramovich, The tropicalization of moduli space](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/AGNES/video.php?f=08-Abramovich)

Answer (score 4):

If you look through the answers given in Martin Brandenburg's comment, someone's linked to MSRI. You may find more videos, by a quick search. What I found some months ago very *informative and useful* is, [*The Classical Algebraic Geometry Today*, MSRI](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/scientific/show/-/event/Wm472). The discussed subjects are so diverse to fill almost everyone's interests. Also, the sound and picture qualities are solid.

Answer (score 4):

There are also three nice [videos of lectures](http://www.theorie.physik.uni-muenchen.de/activities/schools/archiv/2011_asc_school/videos_asc_school_2011/videos_bruzzo/index.html) by Ugo Bruzzo entitled *Algebraic geometry for physicists*.

Comment: is any knowledge of physics is required for understanding these lectures?

Answer (score 4):

There is a complete course on Basic Algebraic Geometry. It is freely available on [NPTEL](http://nptel.ac.in/)

Please click the link below:

[Basic Algebraic Geometry : Varieties, Morphisms, Local Rings, Function Fields and Nonsingularity](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111106097)

Answer (score 2):

Ravi Vakil's online course AGITTOC 2020 , "Algebraic Topology in the Time of COVID".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTEZjR5aNjw

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of lectures [here](https://qgm.au.dk/video/mc/triple-masterclass/index.html) by Indranil Biswas ("Principal Bundles"), Amit Hogadi ("Introduction to Algebraic Stacks"), Nitin Nitsure ("Deformation Theory and Moduli"), and Vikraman Balaji ("Instability and tensor products") during the "Triple masterclass on Algebraic Geometry, June 2014" at the Aarhus University.