# Online Number Theory Video?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-k-theory, online-resources

Are there any graduate level number theory course available on line ? The only video series I am aware of are some MSRI videos, and Ted Chinburg's courses http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/noframes.html, which are hard to see sometimes. I am also looking for good video lectures on algebraic k-theory. Thank you for your sharing information :)

Comment: You might find something in that thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-math-videos 

I vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: For people with the right background, the Eilenberg Lectures of Benedict Gross at Columbia might be extremely useful (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5E0D6DC4BCD8309D).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free includes the videos mentioned in your question and plenty more. 
For #thy I'd say check answer's by Dirk Basson and Felipe Voloch(these are in Portuguese):
http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/aufzeichnungen/SummerSchool/ and
http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-doutorado-2011-geometria-diofantina 