# Are there some websites for self learining of advanced mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, homological-algebra

Are there some websites for self learining of advanced mathematics?
For example, some great lecture vedio of differential geometry, Lie group , Lie algebra, algebraic topology and so on. Thanks

Comment: After some points it's mainly notes, books, papers, and if you're lucky enough sit in grad level seminars/classes. I doubt there are many, if at all, well organized video courses on advance topics.

Comment: If you're looking for videos, then your request is covered by other questions on this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video lectures of mathematics courses available online for free](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free)

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried [MIT OPENCOURSEWARE](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/)

Answer (score 2):

MSRI maintains excellent online videos of talks from most workshops. In many cases there are also lecture notes, and sometimes even notes from a discussion session (or problem session).  The link is here:

http://www.msri.org/web/msri/online-videos

In general these will probably be research-level talks, but there are definitely some introductory talks hiding in there.  As a random example, in Fall 2012, Lauren Williams presented an introductory mini-course on Cluster Algebras.