# Are there any organized websites for seminar/conference videos?

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics, online-resources

These days, there are many conference centers and universities recording seminars and conference talks and make them available on the web. Some examples:

http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive

http://www.birs.ca/videos/2014

http://video.ias.edu/sm

http://www.newton.ac.uk/webseminars/

https://www4.math.duke.edu/video/video.html

However, keeping track of all the websites for these videos is simply not practical. Does anyone know of website that is a bit like arxiv, but for videos? If not, would anyone be interested in starting one? What I have in mind:

1. Everyone can add links for talks that they find interesting.
2. Vidoes are divided into subjects, with tags, like the ones we have on MOF.
3. Weekly email people can subscribe to in order to get latest updates.
4. A discussion board for each video link so that people can add comments and ask questions.

Any other ideas?

Comment: See answers and comments of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-math-videos and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free

Comment: Thanks for the comments. There are some interesting videos on those links. But they are not exactly what I am looking for. I am more looking for a site more systematically organized like arxiv.

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to tags on Vimeo, and in principle arXiv tags like pr.probability could be used
http://vimeopro.com/staff/tutorials/video/741488

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://mtalks.ma.utexas.edu There are no tags or weekly emails (for now at least) but everyone can add links for talks and search through the database.